# UDP socket chat application in java

Tags: java, sockets, udp, chat

I'm trying to create a very simple chat application in Java using UDP sockets. There is one server and multiple clients.

right now my code is :

Server :

```
package chat;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Set;

class User{
    InetAddress addr;
    int port;

    User(InetAddress a,int p){
        addr = a;
        port = p;
    }
}



public class Server {
    private static final int PORT = 27012;
    private static DatagramSocket sckt;
    private static DatagramPacket in,out;
    private static byte[] buffer;
    private static HashMap<String,User> users;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            System.out.println("Opening port...");
            sckt = new DatagramSocket(PORT);
            users = new HashMap<String,User>();

        }
        catch(SocketException e){
            System.out.println("Port connection failed!");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        handleClient();
    }
        private static void sendMsg(InetAddress addr, int port, String msg){
            try{
            out = new DatagramPacket(msg.getBytes(),msg.length(),addr,port);
            sckt.send(out);
            }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    private static void handleClient(){
        try{
            String msgIn,msgOut="",senderNick;
            do{
            buffer = new byte[256];
            in = new DatagramPacket(buffer,buffer.length);
            sckt.receive(in);
            InetAddress clientAddress = in.getAddress();
            int clientPort = in.getPort();
            msgIn = new String(in.getData(),0,in.getLength());
            //print msgIn
            //System.out.println(msgIn);
                        senderNick = msgIn.substring(0,msgIn.indexOf(" "));
                        msgIn = msgIn.substring(msgIn.indexOf(" ")+1);
            if(msgIn.equals("/connect")){
                //String nick = msgIn.substring(msgIn.indexOf(" ") + 1);
                System.out.println(senderNick);
                if(users.containsKey(senderNick)){
                    msgOut = "Nick already in use!";
                }
                else{
                    users.put(senderNick, new User(clientAddress,clientPort));
                    msgOut = "Connected!";
                }
                                sendMsg(clientAddress,clientPort,msgOut);
            }
                        else if(msgIn.equals("/list")){
                            Set userNames;
                            userNames = users.keySet();
                            msgOut = "Users : \n";
                            msgOut += userNames.toString();
                            sendMsg(clientAddress,clientPort,msgOut);
                        }
                        else if(msgIn.startsWith("/msg")){
                            String tmp = msgIn.substring(msgIn.indexOf(" ")+1);
                            String receiverName = tmp.substring(0,tmp.indexOf(" "));
                            String message = tmp.substring(tmp.indexOf(" ")+1);

                            if(!users.containsKey(receiverName)){
                                msgOut = "User " + receiverName + " not found!";
                                sendMsg(clientAddress,clientPort,msgOut);
                            }
                            else{
                                User receiver = users.get(receiverName);
                                msgOut = "Message from "+  senderNick  +" : "+message;
                                sendMsg(clientAddress,clientPort,"Message Sent!");
                                sendMsg(receiver.addr,receiver.port,msgOut);
                            }

                        }
                        else if(msgIn.startsWith("/nick")){
                            String newNick = msgIn.substring(msgIn.indexOf(" ")+1);
                            if(users.containsKey(newNick)){
                                msgOut = "Nick already in use!";
                            }
                            else{
                                users.put(newNick,users.get(senderNick));
                                users.remove(senderNick);
                                msgOut = "Nick changed!";
                            }
                            sendMsg(clientAddress,clientPort,msgOut);
                        }
                        else if(msgIn.equals("/disconnect")){
                            users.remove(senderNick);
                        }

            //out = new DatagramPacket(msgOut.getBytes(),msgOut.length(),clientAddress,clientPort);
            //sckt.send(out);
            }while(true);
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            System.out.println("Closing connection.");
            sckt.close();
        }
    }

}
```

Client :

```
package chat;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Client {

    private static InetAddress host;
    private static final int PORT = 27012;
    private static DatagramSocket sckt;
    private static DatagramPacket in, out;
    private static byte[] buffer;
    private static String nick;

    static class MessageListener implements Runnable {
        //DatagramPacket in;
        //byte[] buffer;
        String reply;
        public void run() {
            do{
            try{
            buffer = new byte[256];
            in = new DatagramPacket(buffer,buffer.length);
            sckt.receive(in);
            reply = new String(in.getData(),0,in.getLength());
            System.out.println("SERVER> "+reply);
            }
            catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }while(true);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            host = InetAddress.getLocalHost();

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.out.println("Host not found!");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        connect();

    }

    private static void sendMsg(String msg) {
        try {
            out = new DatagramPacket(msg.getBytes(), msg.length(), host, PORT);
            sckt.send(out);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void connect() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        try {
            buffer = new byte[256];
            sckt = new DatagramSocket();
            String reply = "";
            do {
                System.out.println("Name: ");
                nick = sc.nextLine();
                sendMsg(nick + " /connect");
                in = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
                sckt.receive(in);
                reply = new String(in.getData(), 0, in.getLength());
                System.out.println("SERVER> " + reply);
            } while (!reply.equals("Connected!"));
            accessServer();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void accessServer() {
        try {
            sckt = new DatagramSocket();
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            String msg = "", reply = "";
            Thread myT = new Thread(new MessageListener());
            myT.start();
            do {
                System.out.print("Enter Message: ");
                msg = sc.nextLine();
                if (!msg.equals("/quit")) {
                    buffer = new byte[256];

                    sendMsg(nick + " " + msg);


                } else {
                    sendMsg(nick + " /disconnect");
                }
            } while (!msg.equals("/quit"));

            sc.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            System.out.println("Connection closing...");
            sckt.close();
        }

    }
}
```

I want to be able to send a message to a single user or to all the users but the problem is that i can't receive the message on the client because as it stands now the client only receives a message after it sends one to the server. So my thought was to use a thread that continuosly listens for messages from the server but it doesn't work. What's the easiest way to go about this ?

Comment: Why do you mean by the thread doesn't work?

Comment: Take a look at Netty library (http://netty.io/)

Comment: @FDinoff I don't really have any experience with threads. I have a MessageListener class in the client and I tried to use that to receive the messages : Right now everything works fine in my chat except that when i send a message to another user the other user doesn't get it.

Comment: @Adrian Post the code so we can look at it. (I am correct in saying that this is the single threaded version right?)

Comment: @FDinoff The code is in the original post. And yes right now it is the single threaded version. I commented the part where I tried to make the thread because it doesn't work.

Comment: @Adrian 1. Go read a tutorial on threads. 2. Don't start a thread every loop and don't read from the socket in two places thats just going to be a race condition.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I changed the MessageListener class so that it now also prints the message received and also changed the accessServer method to start the thread only once instead of every loop. It seems to work fine now with the other stuff but when i try to use /msg the message still doesn't arrive to the destination.

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to use the received datagram immediately, instead of waiting for the thread you created to receive a datagram and populate your `in` variable. You could either handle the received datagram directly in the thread's code, or signal the main thread when a datagram is received using a wait() / notify() scheme.

Comment: I am now handling the received message in the thread code and it seems to work with the other commands but /msg still doesn't work. edited the client code in the original post.